# throwing exception in Policy-Based Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have implemented policy base authorization in my WebApi project. It works fine, the only issue is that I cannot change failure message. After some investigation I find out that this feature is not yet implemented. [Issue tracked here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4670). As a workaround I am thinking to throw an exception instead of `context.Fail()`.

Is it a good idea? Can this have some issues?

Sample code:

```
public class MySampleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MySampleRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        MySampleRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("My custom message");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should be... exceptional. Policy violations aren't exceptional but expected.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but this is hopefully only until there will be some way to set a custom message on policy violation. Temporary workaround.